# How do I call a function inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is probably a very simple answer to what would seem and should be so simple and routine.

From within the $(document).ready(), I want to call a function with a jQuery object - and SPECIFICALLY, this can not be attached to an asynchronous event like mouseover or click.

The code below actually seems to work.. but I think that I'm still calling 
fnShowCard as a handler for the .on method.  I simply want to call fnShowCard with the object and parameter or two.

I can't seem to find a single example that does this without associating the call to an event (like click). The only "event" I care about is document ready...

Thanks in advance!

```
  $(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );


    $(".tools-card:contains('CMS')").on(fnShowCard());


  });
  // End Document ready



  /**
   * fnShowCard
   */
  function fnShowCard() {

    console.log(">>> Begin fnShowCard: ");


    // First find the end of the row
    var cardClicked = $(this);
    var currentCard = cardClicked;
    var nextCard = $(this).next();

  }
```

Comment: Nikola... if you can't be helpful, go away. You did not read the question. I specifically asked how to do this without attaching it to an event (such as click). The alleged duplicate question first was not a duplicate and second, provided an answer used the click event

Comment: I still don't see question. For example "inside jQuery" is not correct title. Initial setup always come inside JQ on document ready. This event is also nothing special he trigger when DOM elements are available for script manipulation.See : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ is also method without special permission like 'click' event. You just need to call it in someway. Make better title is my suggestion. Anyway i remove flag and disappear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use each()

```
$(".tools-card:contains('CMS')").each(fnShowCard);
```

Comment: Awesome!  I knew it was simple... another way that I can do this is to define the jQuery object from within the function (method ((I still can't get used to calling a function a method :) )) and just pass the parameter that I want to select on...

Answer (score 1):

Just use each method instead of event listener "on"